# What does selecting "none" queue do?

Tags: pfsense, traffic-shaping

I'm [trying to shape traffic in pfSense](https://superuser.com/questions/819470/how-to-limit-bandwidth-used-by-an-ip-in-the-penalty-box-in-pfsense).

The question comes up of [which queue to assign traffic to](https://superuser.com/questions/819515/why-can-the-ackqueue-not-be-the-same-as-the-queue).

What happens if i pick **none** as a queue?

[image]

In the end, traffic going out the link is under the control of a traffic shaper. In the end, the traffic shaper is going to have to handle this traffic. What does the traffic shaper do with *none* traffic?

- does it count as super-high priority traffic, bypassing all shaper rules and being processed before any traffic that has been assigned to a queue?
- if that is the case, how is it different from assigning the traffic to the `qLink` queue?

  [image]
- does any `none` categorized traffic get sent into the *default* queue, processed as though it were it were uncategorized, and fall into the *default* queue?
- if that is the case, how is it different from assigning the traffic to the `qDefault` queue?

  [image]

In order for traffic shaping to be effective, i **need** `ack` packets to have super-super-super low priority. How do i do that when the UI won't let me assign the ack packets to the super-super-super low priority queue?